# .Map to a specific type in Scala

Tags: xml, scala

I have a couple of case classes with a structure kind of like:

```
case class Book(title: String, pages: Int, pages: List[Page])
case class Page(words: String, otherField: String)
```

I am trying to load them from an XML file using map in Scala

```
object Parser {
  def loadBook(): Book = {
    val bookFile = scala.xml.XML.loadFile("/conf/PageConfig.xml")
    val pages = (bookFile \\ "pages" ).map { pageNode =>
      val page = loadPage(pageNode)
    }
    Book((bookFile \ "title").text, (bookFile \ "pages").text, pages)
  }

  def loadPage(pageNode): Page = { 
    Page((pageNode \ "words"), (pageNode \ "otherField"))
  }
```

This code is modified from my original but I tried to get it as close as possible. The problem I am having is that `pages` is a `sec[Unit]` object but I want it to be a `List[Page]` object. I don't have a great functional programming background. Is there something I am not understanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is occurring because the last line in your `map` lambda is an assignment.  Assignment expressions evaluate to `Unit`.  What you want is the following:

```
val pages = (bookFile \ "pages" ).map { pageNode =>
  loadPage(pageNode)
}
```

That should get you a `sec[Page]`.  To convert it to a `List[Page]`, use the `toList` method on the result.

Comment: Was about to ask about that `seq` to `list`. I am new to scala why does it return `Unit` there?

Comment: An assignment statement is of type `Unit`, `void` in other parts of the world. By removing the assignment, which isn't used anyway, the value of the lambda expression is a `Page`s, and the `map` produces a `Seq[Page]`.

Comment: Yeah, after I posted it, I realized I left that part out. :)  As for assignments evaluating to `Unit`, that's what all assignments evaluate to.  This is related to the fundamental difference between a _statement_ based language and an _expression_ based language.  `loadPage(pageNode)` is an expression which evaluates to an object of type `Page`.  But the assignment of that `Page` object to a value is an expression which always evaluates to `Unit`

Comment: Ah I see... that is the best explanation of that concept I have seen yet

Comment: Awesome, glad we could help!